# proving that a function is homomorphism of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

[image]

I am stuck with this problem.. Can someone please help me? I know the definition of isomorphism, homomorphism, injective, and surjective but that's pretty much it. :(

so part a) it satisfies the first condition f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b) (of being homomorphism) by definition but how would i show the second condition f(ab) = f(a)f(b) ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've proved $\bar h$ is compatible with addition and multiplication in a ring is distributive with respect to addition, all one has to do is checking compatibility with multiplication for monomials:
\begin{align*}\bar h(aX^m\cdot bX^n)&=\bar h(abX^{m+n})=h(ab)X^{m+n}=h(a) h(b) X^m X^n\\&=h(a) X^m \cdot h(b) X^n=\bar h(aX^m)\cdot\bar h(bX^n).\end{align*}